# Malloc failing when called via ctypes from a c thread

Tags: python, multithreading, ctypes

I'm using Python's CTypes to bind to a shared library; I have a callback registered with this library, which is called in the context of a thread that the library itself creates. I've found that if I call `libc.malloc()` (`libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')`) from within my callback, that it returns bogus values. Not `NULL`, but an address which will cause a segfault if I dereference it.

Can anyone provide me with any insight to what may be happening, or alternatively, tell me that they call `malloc()` in the same way, and that it works for them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you properly anottating the malloc call so that ctypes know it should return pointers not integers? (Doubly so if you are working on a 64bit box?)

Answer (score 0):

The code below works on Windows.  Should be similar on Linux.  It should even work without the explicit `argtypes/restype` attributes set, at least on 32-bit systems.

```
from ctypes import *

crt = CDLL('msvcrt')
malloc = crt.malloc
malloc.argtypes = [c_size_t]
malloc.restype = c_void_p
free = crt.free
free.argtypes = [c_void_p]
free.restype = None

n = cast(malloc(10),POINTER(c_ubyte))
for i in range(10):
    print '{:02X}'.format(n[i]),
free(n)
```

Since you mentioned a callback, make sure you keep a reference to the callback for the life of its use.  This means do not call it like:

```
set_callback(CFUNCTYPE(...)(callback_func))
```

The CFUNCTYPE object is destroyed right after setting the callback.  Instead do:

```
@CFUNCTYPE(...)
def callback_func(...)
    ...

set_callback(callback_func)
```

This decorator form replaces the Python function object with the ctypes callback object for the life of the module (or class, if a method).